# Accessing an SSE register variable

Tags: c++, sse

I want to access the indvidual elements of SSE variable. Is that possible. For example,

```
    __m128i a = _mm_set_epi32(10,15,20,30);
```

Now, I want to access only the first element. for example 30 in above case. I saw previous example in stackoverflow as

```
    int *val = (int*) &a;
```

and then accessing by val[0]. But i don't want any intermediate variable. I tried something like below

```
   int b = ((int*)a[0]) and similarly other things.
```

But i ended up in no luck.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

There is an intrinsic for this: [_mm_cvtsi128_si32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/5z7a9642(v=vs.100).aspx). [Do not treat a __mm128 as a memory variable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ayeb3ayc.aspx): This forces a spill and prevents it from being put in a register.

Answer (score 1):

You were close, you were getting the [precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) wrong:

```
__m128i a = _mm_set_epi32(10,15,20,30);
// int b = ((int*)a[0]); // [] has more precedence, wrong
int b = ((int*)&a)[0]; // Right
cout << b;
```

Edit: as Raymond noted [it is discouraged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ayeb3ayc.aspx) to treat a `__m128i` as a memory variable.

Thus I'm also voting for [_mm_cvtsi128_si32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/5z7a9642(v=vs.100).aspx)

```
__m128i a = _mm_set_epi32(10,15,20,30);
std::cout << _mm_cvtsi128_si32(a);
```